# React error: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to run this code (picked up from some source) where inputs are created dynamically and values are recorded on submit.
I'm getting this error:

> Cannot read property 'users' of undefined while calling createUI.

Can someone help me here, please?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    users: [{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]
  });

  const addClick = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      users: [...prevState.users, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }];
    });
  };
  const createUI = () => {
    state.users.map((el, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
            placeholder="First Name"
            name="firstName"
            value={el.firstName || ""}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            placeholder="Last Name"
            name="lastName"
            value={el.lastName || ""}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input type="button" value="remove" onClick={removeClick} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  const handleChange = (i, e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let users = [...state.users];
    users[i] = { ...users[i], [name]: value };
    setState({ users });
  };

  const removeClick = i => {
    let users = [...state.users];
    users.splice(i, 1);
    setState({ users });
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.users));
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {createUI()}
      <input type="button" value="add more" onClick={addClick()} />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

// const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
// ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement)
```

Sandbox here -> 
https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-fields-23cw4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: 1) `onClick={addClick()}` should be `onClick={addClick}`. 2) You need to wrap the object with `()` in `addClick`. 3) You need to `return state.users.map` from `createUI` function

Comment: 4) change `onChange` to: `onChange={e => handleChange(i, e)}` Otherwise, you get the event as the first argument not the index

Comment: Thanks @adiga 
and thanks a lot everyone for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 3 issues with your code,

1. you executed your onclick handler, addClick which triggered inifinite loop
2. createUI method did not return the array of created components
3. addClick function's setState syntax was not correct.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    users: [{ firstName: "", lastName: "" }]
  });

  const addClick = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      return { users: [...prevState.users, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }] };
    });
  };
  const createUI = () => {
    return state.users.map((el, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
            placeholder="First Name"
            name="firstName"
            value={el.firstName || ""}
            onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e, i)}
          />
          <input
            placeholder="Last Name"
            name="lastName"
            value={el.lastName || ""}
            onChange={(e)=>handleChange(e, i)}
          />
          <input type="button" value="remove" onClick={removeClick} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    let users = [...state.users];
    users[i] = { ...users[i], [name]: value };
    setState({ users });
  };

  const removeClick = i => {
    let users = [...state.users];
    users.splice(i, 1);
    setState({ users });
  };

  const handleSubmit = event => {
    alert("A name was submitted: " + JSON.stringify(this.state.users));
    event.preventDefault();
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {createUI()}
      <input type="button" value="add more" onClick={addClick} />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: not able to enter any values in the input boxes with the changes you posted. Can you please have a look.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh: Check the code input are working in the above snippet now

Comment: Thanks, it's working with the onChange changes now.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh Another FYI: you also need to change `onClick={e => removeClick(i, e)}` Otherwise it will remove the wrong index

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that error is the following line:

```
<input type="button" value="add more" onClick={addClick()} />
```

Technically you are calling the `addClick` function which changes the value of your `state` object. The solution which works fine is the following:

```
<input type="button" value="add more" onClick={() => addClick()} />
```

Or shorter way:

```
<input type="button" value="add more" onClick={addClick} />
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Just `onClick={addClick}` should be fine

Comment: There are couple more errors. Like OP isn't returning from `createUI` function. They don't have `()` wrapper around the object in `addClick`

Comment: Thanks, it helps
but it seems like my ui is messed up now. On clicking "add more" everything is gone. It's a blank screen
I was expecting at least a pair of input box to be there initially and thereafter can add more with "add more" button. On submit should display these values with an alert.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @norbiial's answer which should be the accepted answer: Your `addClick` function is incorrect. Your `setState` call is not returning anything which means as soon as you click the add button it will break again.

Change to this:

```js
const addClick = () => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    users: [...prevState.users, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }]
  }));
};
```

The same issue will be seen in `createUI`.

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1:**

if you are returning an Object without return statement it should be wrapped in a bracket

`const addClick = () => {
    setState(prevState => ({
      users: [...prevState.users, { firstName: "", lastName: "" }];
    }));
};`

**Error 2:**

Missing return statement,

`const createUI = () => {
    return state.users.map((el, i) => {
      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <input
            placeholder="First Name"
            name="firstName"
            value={el.firstName || ""}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input
            placeholder="Last Name"
            name="lastName"
            value={el.lastName || ""}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <input type="button" value="remove" onClick={removeClick} />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };`

**Error 3:**

`onClick` should have a function, but you are setting a value returned from `addClick` which is `undefined`

`...
<input type="button" value="add more" onClick={addClick} />
...`

Comment: thanks, it fixes a lot of issues here, but I'm still not able to type in any values in the input boxes